# Javascript setTimeout with 0 delay issue

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I noticed a strange behavior: if I have a series of tasks and wish to defer their execution, then I can use a setTimeout with 0 delay for each of them.
(see http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth#the-settimeout-func-0-trick)

Everything works perfectly: the tasks are queued and executed as soon as possible.

But ... if the invocation of the various setTimeout **is very close**, then I found that sometimes (rarely happens!) is not executed in the **correct order**.
Why?

Comment: Why not just use `1ms` and it should work...

Comment: If you want correct order, chain them. That's the only surefire way to go.

Comment: What's the "correct order" if the delay is the same ? It's not defined.

Comment: @dystroy the order in which they're enqueued, I assume

Comment: @JanDvorak I was pointing at the fact there was no reason to assume that. I looked before at the spec and nowhere did I see anything regarding this point.

Comment: @dystroy nor did I, but it's a nice property nevertheless, even if not true in case of `setTimeout` :-)

Comment: Didn't the question change ? What do you mean by "very close" ?

Comment: I did not manage to replicate your observation, in IE, Firefox OR Chrome. All of them did preserve the order: http://jsfiddle.net/Uc5rv/

Comment: @Didax Since you're deferring various functions with setTimeout, wouldn't that mean overlaps in execution occur and depending on the time of execution for each setTimeout block you'd get the impression that they occurred in different succession ?

Comment: As I said it is not an error that happens "always".
This is an error that occurs rarely and only in certain stressful situations.
However I think @dystroy suggestion is the right one: if I set the same delay I'm not setting an explicit order.
Launch one after the other "setTimeout" with the same delay is not equivalent to setting an implicit order.

Comment: In fact you're in some kind of grey area. No spec says the order should be the insertion order but it seems almost obvious and as somebody who implemented a few schedulers I don't see why the implementations wouldn't respect this natural contract : it's not hard or costly to respect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody ever promised they would be fired in the "correct" order (the tasks with the same timeout will be executed in the order they are set to time out). `setTimeout` only guarantees that:

- each timeout is executed exactly once (unless the page dies in the meantime)
- each timeout is executed no sooner than when it is supposed to.

There is no word about execution order. In fact, even if the implementor *tried* to preserve order (even as a side-effect), most likely there is not enough time resolution to provide a unique sort order to all tasks, and a binary heap (which may well be used here) does not preserve insertion order of equal keys).

If you want to preserve the order of your deferred tasks, you should only enqueue one when the previous one is done.

This should work:

```
var defer = (function(){
  //wrapped in IIFE to provide a scope for deferreds and wrap
  var running = false;
  var deferreds = [];
  function wrap(func){
    return function(){
      func();
      var next = deferreds.shift();
      if(next){
        setTimeout(wrap(next),0);
      }else{
        running = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return function(func){
    if(running){
      deferreds.push(func);
    }else{
      setTimeout(wrap(func),0);
      running = true;
    }
  }
})()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x2QuB/1/

Comment: +1 because that's the sanest solution. It looks like a few chars at missing at the end but the principle is the good one.

Comment: @dystroy I've noticed them as well. Added.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using jquery deferreds ( or some other implementation of deferreds), which can handle this pattern very elegantly.

The important point to note is that the deferred done callbacks are executed in the order in which they are added.

```
 var createCountFn  = function(val){  
    return function(){ 
        alert(val)
    };
}

 // tasks 
var f1 = createCountFn(1),
    f2 = createCountFn('2nd'),
    f3 = createCountFn(3);

 var dfd = $.Deferred();
 dfd.done(f1).done(f2).done(f3);

 dfd.resolve();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gtk6f/1/)

Comment: Nice, but they aren't really deferred; you would need `setTimeout(function(){dfd.resolve()},0)`, for starters

Comment: @JanDvorak. I see that. As I understand the problem, the main aim is to execute a series of tasks(if we may call these functions),  in a pre-defined order. Now , if it is desired to start execution of these tasks after the execution of the current method, then we need to add the setTimeout, as you mentioned.

Comment: @In a predefined order, and after the current method, IIUC. Also note that you cannot defer additional methods from those deferred methods.

Comment: I still like this solution for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 draft specification states that the setTimeout method can be run asynchronously (implying that the order that the callbacks will be executed may not be preserved), which could be what your browser is doing.

> #### [The setTimeout() method must run the following steps:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout)
>
> > **...**
> >
> > 6. Return handle, and then continue running this algorithm asynchronously.
> >
> > 7. If the method context is a Window object, wait until the Document associated with the method context has been fully active for a further *timeout* milliseconds (not necessarily consecutively).

In any case one could workaround this issue by doing something similar to this:

```
function inOrderTimeout(/* func1[, func2, func3, ...funcN], timeout */)
{   var timer; // for timeout later
    var args = arguments; // allow parent function arguments to be accessed by nested functions
    var numToRun = args.length - 1; // number of functions passed
    if (numToRun < 1) return; // damm, nothing to run
    var currentFunc = 0; // index counter
    var timeout = args[numToRun]; // timeout should be straight after the last function argument
    (function caller(func, timeout) // name so that recursion is possible
    {   if (currentFunc > numToRun - 1)
        {   // last one, let's finish off
            clearTimeout(timer);
            return;
        }
        timer = setTimeout(function () 
        {   func(); // calls the current function
            ++currentFunc; // sets the next function to be called
            caller(args[currentFunc], timeout);
        }, Math.floor(timeout));
    }(args[currentFunc], timeout)); // pass in the timeout and the first function to run
}
```

Comment: Even if the code were running synchronously, execution order may not be preserved.

Comment: @JanDvorak I guess so, especially if 2 items were scheduled to run on the same "tick" (especially due to load activity, making it unable to do it before), where it would not be able to tell which one was scheduled first.

Comment: Note that "asynchronously" in the spec probably means "out of order / delayed", not "in parallel". The tasks are guaranteed to be asynchronous in this sense.